# Sharepoint 2013 Check if path folder exists

Tags: caml, query

I have a query like this:

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where>
                       <In><FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" />
                         <Values>
                           <Value Type="Text">/sites/folders/folder1</Value>
                         </Values>
                       </In></Where></Query></View>');`
```

And I would like to put a condition before that executes this if the path exists. How can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You can look into REST API to check if folder exists. You can call below REST API.

`http://<SITE NAME>/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<TARGET FOLDER>')/Folders?$filter=Name eq '<NEW FOLDER NAME>'`

In you case the query might look something like this.

`http://<SITE NAME>/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('folders')/Folders?$filter=Name eq 'folder1'`

If folder exists you will gets its details in the response, else you will get empty response.

Answer (score 0):

the below code snippet (using JSOM) showing how to determine whether a folder **exists, not exist or exist but don't have access:**

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var folder = ctx.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/folderurl");
ctx.load(folder, "Exists", "Name");
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
      if (folder.get_exists()) {
         // Folder exists 
         console.log(folder.get_name());
      }
      else {
         console.log("Folder hidden for security permissions");
      }
   },
   function(s, args) {
      if (args.get_errorTypeName() === "System.IO.FileNotFoundException") {
         //Folder does not exist
         console.log("Folder does not exist.");
      }
      else {
         // An unexpected error occurred.
         console.log("args.get_message());
      }
   }
);
```